# react-native ios get mac address

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

In the react-native application I use the react-native-device-info library to get the MAC address of the device.

But I can only get the mac address of Android devices. I could not find a library to get the mac address of iOs devices.

How do I get the MAC address of iOs devices?

Comment: Yup, clearly in info of this library. It stats that it doesn't show MAC address for IOS device.

Answer (score 9):

There is no way of doing this in `iOS 7` or later, [citing apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013162-SW1):

> In iOS 7 and later, if you ask for the MAC address of an iOS device, the system returns the value 02:00:00:00:00:00. If you need to identify the device, use the identifierForVendor property of UIDevice instead.

Instead, you should use `identifierForVendor` which could be received with `react-native-device-info`:

```js
    import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info'; 

    const uniqueId = DeviceInfo.getUniqueID();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers.

Is the variable UniqueID constant?

I was going to do the license according to the mac address in my react-native application, but that does not seem possible. I can do it with the UniqueID value, but the users have to give me this value.

Where can users see the UniqueID value from both iOS and android devices and tell me?

Comment: The UniqueID is constant and unique within the same app. Therefore you must display it somewhere in your app and ask your users to look there.

Comment: Unfortunatelly the "UniqueID" is renewed after the App reinstall both on iOS and Android. I am still searching for something more reliable.